# Bash command 'read' error "not identifier: -t"

Tags: bash, shell-script

I wrote this very simple script at the end of my /etc/profile:

```
    i=3
    let key
    while [ $i -gt 0 ] ; do
        printf "\rPress 'q' to prevent starting X ($i)"
        read -rsn 1 -t 1 key # THE PROBLEM IS HERE
        if [[ $? == 0 ]] ; then
            break;
        fi
        i=$[$i-1]
    done

    if [[ $key != "q" ]]; then
        printf "\nStarting X..."
        exec startx
    fi
```

This script allows me to choose whether to start X or not when I log in.
The same script works (without 'exec startx') as expected when I execute it by myself. But during **profile** script execution it stops on **read** command waiting for user input without a timeout, and after pressing any key I see the error: "not identifier: -t".

Comment: Are you sure you are running this code with `bash` and not with `zsh`?  What is the `#!`-line of the script and how _exactly_ is it being invoked?

Comment: Oh, yes, I use zsh as a default shell. And I invoked the script as a bash script. But I still can't realize what's wrong with the '-t' parameter. I can't find information about differences in usage of the 'read' utility in zsh and in bash. I would appreciate it if you could explain to me what actually I do wrong.

Comment: The `-n` option to the `read` built-in utility does quite different things in `bash` and in `zsh` (causing `-t` to be taken as a variable to read in `zsh`). You seem to be running the script with `zsh`. What is the `#!`-line of the script, and exactly how do you invoke the script when it fails?

Answer (score 0):

Probably two different issues here:

1. Your profile cannot be running anything in the profile using a shebang. Profiles have to be sourced because they export all kinds of  variables for use by the login shell. If a shebang starts a different shell in a profile, then its effects would disappear when that script completes. No child process can affect the environment of its parent.
2. At the time your profile is executed, you probably don't yet have a terminal open that can listen for a response to the read.